# Certificate Authority for multiple keys

Tags: certificate-authority

I have a single server hosting an existing self-signed CA with keys for OpenVPN.
Can I used the same CA and generate keys for freeradius?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Essentially yes, but you'll have to make sure the certificates (not keys) you generate contain the data freeradius will look for. What that is depends on how freeradius is set up, what you use it for.

If you use `easy-rsa` (supplied with OpenVPN), you'll probably need to edit the `openssl.cnf` file it uses to generate certificates that are also suitable for your freeradius use-case.

Dealing with X.509 certificates is not fun; documentation is ambiguous and dense, many standards are old and weren't written with the Internet in mind, and in many cases they're also vague. Prepare to have to blaze your own trail.